# How to integrate stripe in ionic 4 with Firebase functions?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments, ionic4

i try to integrate Stripe in a ionic 4 with firebase so i follow this tuto :

https://medium.com/enappd/integrating-stripe-payment-in-ionic-4-for-apps-and-pwa-de05142c523e

But that doen's work fireBase send an error.

So i try to disable cors but this still doesn't working

This is the functions

```js
exports.payWithStripe = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
   production
    cors(request, response, () => {
        response.status(200).send({test: 'Testing functions'});
    stripe.charges.create({
        amount: request.body.amount,
        currency: request.body.currency,
        source: resquest.body.token,
    }).then((charge) => {
```

That is the fireBase error log

```html
{ Error: Must provide source or customer.
    at Function.generate (/srv/node_modules/stripe/lib/Error.js:49:16)
    at IncomingMessage.res.once (/srv/node_modules/stripe/lib/StripeResource.js:167:39)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30)
    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:139:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:219:9)
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your request.body.token field is not actually sending the source id, which should be generated client-side by stripe.js.

```
stripe.createSource( cardElement, result => {
  // Do something with this source ID
  result.source.id;
});
```

Comment: Hi, ty to your fast reponse but im absolut beginner in stripe so the problem come from client side ? in the console of client side i have the token id who is generate

Comment: Can we see your client-side code that calls the function?

Answer (score 0):

For testing purposes please add as following to your index.js file in functions folder.

(please kindly note that this is extremely for testing purposes)

```
stripe.charges.create({
        amount: '40000',
        currency: 'huf',
        source: 'tok_visa',
    }).then((charge) => {
```